# why is this async matrix multiplication code slower than synchronous?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm trying to implement a matrix multiplication function that is faster than my synchronous multiplication function by using concurrent.futures.threadPoolExecutor() threads. Here is the code:

```
def asyncmult(m1, m2):
threads = []
prod = np.zeros((m1.shape[0], m2.shape[1]))

def multvecs(inp):
    vec1, vec2, index = inp
    i, j = index
    sum = 0
    for k in range(vec1.shape[0]):
        sum += vec1[k] * vec2[k]
    prod[i][j] = sum

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for i in range(m1.shape[0]):
        for j in range(m2.shape[1]):
            f = executor.submit(multvecs, (m1[i], m2[:, j], (i, j)))
            threads.append(f)
return prod
```

on plotting against time taken with increase in input matrix size this function performs the worse than synchronous.
why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Comment: Why do you think this would perform better or the same? This is all CPU bound code, so multiple threads aren't going to help you in CPython, and will only hurt due to the overhead.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock . However, using thread is not the most efficient way to speed up you program. In fact it is pretty inefficient. Put it shortly, parallelism in CPython is a mess. You should use vectorization instead. See: https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html .